# How to pass HDFS input data for MapReduce program

Tags: hadoop, intellij-idea, mapreduce

I've installed hadoop2.7.3 and run typical MapReduce program using official codes in [hadoop site](http://hadoop.apache.org). For running MapReduce program I use Intellij IDE and created a Maven project. I added `hadoop-core` dependency and created a new run configuration that I set `Program arguments` field
 in there.

[image]

So I have two question:

1- I've set `Program arguments` to `input` and `output` in my project directory and my input files are in `input` directory. We know `input` directory is `local` directory and my question is how can I pass input from `HDFS` to my MapReduce program ? I've tried creating input directory in HDFS and pass it's address (that is under hdfs) to `Program argument` but it errors!

2- My second question is, do we need to have `hadoop` installed to run such a mapreduce programs? You know I add `hadoop-core` to the dependencies and the program use it to run and I feel there is no need to have `hadoop` installed.

Comment: If you run your map reduce program through command line you have to pass input files and output dir path in the Driver code .
FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job , new Path(args[0]) ;
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job , new Path(args[1]) ;

Where args is the commands you pass through command line.
hadoop jar /path to jar  DriverClass /input_dir /output_dir

Comment: @rohitgoel yes, I've tried that before. But is there any way to do it through Intellij?

Comment: If you were unable to run it through command line i can help but i dont how to run through intellij